# Utilizing Boto3 to connect to verify if any s3 buckets that consist any ACL or Bucket policy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python script that is working half way, it errors-out at `for bucket in conn.buckets.all()`.

Here is what I have got so far:

[image: Code]

The error is:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets
>   operation: Access Denied: ClientError ClientError: An error occurred
>   (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

I have given full access to the user and the policy that is attached to the role that is being used by the Lambda function.

Comment: Where is this code running? In a Lambda function, on an EC2 instance, or on your own computer?

Comment: Please provide the code as text in code formatting. Not as an image.

Comment: it is running it in the lambda function. Since i am new to Stackvoeroverflow, it is not allowing me to post the code into the post. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

conn.buckets.all() returns a list of buckets already; the next two lines after the for loop should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone, it was just the permission issue with the role that was utilized by the lambda function. LIST permission were not specified.